# How can I remove all vowels in a sentence except for the vowel at the first letter?

Tags: string, perl

What is wrong specifically with this code? How can I correct it?

```
$x = "without any vowels after the first letter\n";
foreach $i (@x[1..]) {
    if ($i =~ /[AEIOUaeiou]/) {
        $x =~ tr/A E I O U a e i o u//d;
    }
}
print "$x\n";
```

I tried `[1..]` to exclude the first letter. If it does not work, how else can I remove the first letter?

---

**EDIT**  I edited code to make it syntactically (mostly) correct to convey their obvious original idea, except for the attempt to index into a string which isn't correct in Perl. (Clarifying that is a part of what I consider useful in this question.)

Comment: "_What is wrong specifically with this code?_"  --- just about everything -- most of what's written is not valid Perl, or really any programming language.  I'd suggest to work through a Perl tutorial, if it's Perl you want/need to use, so to be able to use the language sensibly.  It doesn't take long at all to pick up the basics.  (And, I don't see how you could implement an answer to the actual question?)

Comment: Perhaps you will find usefull [Modern Perl](http://modernperlbooks.com/), [Beginning Perl](https://learn.perl.org/books/beginning-perl/).

Comment: Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/69218900/2766176

Comment: @briandfoy It isn't -- they want to leave the first character in each word unaffected in that question, here they want to leave only the very first character of the string.  So simple solutions of that other question don't go here.  (Also, this question came first and is no worse than the other.)

Comment: It's the same question and the same idea. It's just a matter of how you define what you think a word is. This is the case of there only being one word and allowing spaces.

Answer (score 2):

First, most of that is not Perl, or any programming language for that matter.  I'd suggest to work through a Perl tutorial of your choice *first*, before trying to get solutions for specific problems.  However, here's an answer since the problem itself is of enough interest in general.

Next, in Perl you can't directly index into a string, so you can't skip the first character(s) like that.

But you can separate that first character in the string and process the rest (removing vowels), of course. One way with regex<sup>†</sup>

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $str = shift // 'out with ALL vowels after first';

$str =~ s/.\K(.*)/ $1 =~ tr{[aeiouAEIOU]}{}dr /e;

say $str;    #-->  ot wth LL vwls ftr frst
```

This relies on the `/e` modifier, which makes it so that the replacement side is evaluated as code, and so it runs an independent [transliteration (`tr`)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#y/SEARCHLIST/REPLACEMENTLIST/cdsr) there, processing the captured substring.

Then we need the [`/r` modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta#Non-destructive-substitution) in that embedded `tr`/regex, to *return* the new string instead of changing the old one in place -- what wouldn't be possible anyway as one can't change `$1`.

One can also use a regex insteda of `tr`, less efficient but with its many conveniences

```
$str =~ s/.\K(.*)/ $1 =~ s{[aeiou]}{}igr /e;
```

Now we can use far more sophisticated tools in that regex than in `tr`; in this case it's only the `i` flag, for case-**i**nsensitive.

If it were more than the one first character to keep change `.` to `.{N}`.

---

<sup>†</sup>  Regex is not compulsory, of course.  A more elementary take: [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split) the string into its first character and the rest, then use `tr` on the rest

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $str = shift // q(out with ALL vowels after first);

my ($result, $rest) = split //, $str, 2;  # first char, rest of string

$result .= $rest =~ tr/aeiouAEIOU//dr;  # prune $rest of vowels, append to $result

say $result;
```

Then put this in a little mini subroutine.  To change the original string in place, instead of getting a new (`$result`) string, use it (`$str`) everywhere instead of `$result`.

I am not sure about how it compares efficiency wise but it may well fare well.

For the curiosity's sake, here it is in a single statement

```
$str = join '', map { length > 1 ? tr/aeiouAEIOU//dr : $_ }  split //, $str, 2;
```

This specifically uses the fact that only the first (one) character need be skipped; that is easily made dynamical, as long as the criterion does involve the length of substrings.

More importantly, this assumes that the rest of the string is longer than 1 character.  To drop that assumption change the criterion

```
use feature 'state';

$str = join '', map { 
    state $chr_cnt = 0; 
    ++$chr_cnt > 1 ? tr/aeiouAEIOU//dr : $_ 
} 
split //, $str, 2;
```

This also relies on leaving aside just one character. It uses a [feature](https://perldoc.perl.org/feature) to keep a lexical value across executions, [state](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/state).

A more generic solution, which uses the property of [substr](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr) to be possible to write to

```
substr($str, 1) =~ tr/aeiouAEIOU//d;
```

Here it's much cleaner and simpler to relax the limitation to the first character: just change that `1` in order to skip more characters.  The tricky -- unexpected -- part here may be that normally builtins can't be written *to* like that, they aren't [lvalue subroutines](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub#Lvalue-subroutines)

Comment: Hello, thanks. We haven't been introduced with regex so as a first year student I am working on with what we have learned so far. Is there another way of doing it using for loops? That was what I was trying to do.

Comment: @Traveller Hi -- what you showed tries to use `tr`, which is a regex-style idea.  Yes, you can do it by elementary means -- break the string into characters and iterate over that list, keeping only those that satisfy your criteria: either the first one, or not-vowel.  (But then again, to check whether a character is not a vowel you'd use a regex -- because an alternative isn't pretty -- a five-way `if` statement!) But you can't really do that without first learning at least _some_ Perl!

Comment: This is my assignment due on Monday. So, without regex, I need to split it into words and  write an if statement later on.

Comment: @Traveller A basic way: split into characters (not "words"), then iterate through that list comparing each to vowels; if it matches any one vowel it's not kept.  If you can't use regex than I think you'd have to do `eq` to each of the vowels in turn.  Skip the first one, which is kept.  But -- you try with `tr` -- is that allowed? If yes, then split the string into the firts character and the rest, and apply `tr` to the rest, then merge them back.

Comment: @Traveller  (I don't know though how you are going to do it in Perl when you clearly have no idea of the language? Can you pick up the very basics in a few days? It's possible.)

Comment: @Traveller To split a string: `my @parts = split /PATTERN/, $str;` where `PATTERN` is a full-on regex.  To split into characters use an empty pattern, so `my @chars = split //, $str;`.  To split off the first one, use the fourth argument, `my ($first, $rest) = split '', $str, 2;`, which limits into how many pieces this is split. See [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split). Note, in the first case we got an array (starts with `@`, in this second one two scalars (variables start with `$`).  So now you can run `tr` on `$rest`, etc.

Comment: This one works: $s = "without any vowels after the first letter\n";
$s =~ tr/a e i o u//d;
print "$s\n";

Comment: So, I thought this one would work as well: $x = "without any vowels after the first letter\n";
foreach $i in @x[1..] {
    if $i "AEIOUaeiou"
    $x =~ tr/A E I O U a e i o u//d
}
print "$x\n";

Comment: I have asked, we have to use tr/A E I O U a e i o u//d method for this assignment

Comment: @Traveller (1) That "works" because the first character isn't a vowel anyway; otherwise, it doesn't, that removes _all_ vowels, period. (2) But, that next code you are showing is.not.Perl, at all (I told you that twice already :).  So it can't work.

Comment: "_we have to use_" -- ah, OK.  Then see the footnote in my answer, that relies on `tr`.  But-- I have no idea what your class/assignment/prof are like, at all; so adapt that code to what it should be.  Again: i very strongly recommend you learn the basics of the language first.

Comment: I think you are working too hard to get `s/[a-z]\K[aeiou]+//g;`

Comment: @briandfoy They want to leave only the very first character in the string (not of every word).  At least that's my understanding...  (Their next question, which seemed the same to me at first, is asking to leave the first character of each word. )

Answer (score -1):

The algorithm for solution of the problem is in your question

- add letter to a string   if it isn't vowel
- add letter to the string if it is first vowel in the input string

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $x = "without any vowels after the first letter\n";
my($o,$count) = ('',0);

print 'IN:  ' . $x;

for ( split('',$x) ) {
    $o .= $_ unless $count != 0 and /[aeiou]/i;
    $count++ if /[aeiou]/i;
}

print 'OUT: ' . $o;
```

Output

```
IN:  without any vowels after the first letter
OUT: witht ny vwls ftr th frst lttr
```

Addendum: OP's clarification of the problem

- look at each word in the sentence
- if a word starts from vowel then delete all vowels but first one
- if a word starts from none vowel then delete all vowels

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $x = 'I like apples more than oranges';
my @o;

say 'IN:  ' . $x;

for ( split(' ', $x) ) {
    if ( /^[aeiou]/i ) {
        s/.\K(.*)/$1 =~ tr|aeiouAEIOU||dr/e;
    } else {
        tr|aeiouAEIOU||d;
    }
    @o = (@o,$_);
}

say 'OUT: ' . join(' ', @o);
```

Output

```
IN:  I like apples more than oranges
OUT: I lk appls mr thn orngs
```

Or in perlish style

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $x = "I like apples more than oranges";

say 'IN:  ' . $x;
say 'OUT: ' . join(' ', map { s/.\K(.*)/$1 =~ tr|aeiouAEIOU||dr/e && $_ } split('[ ]+', $x));
```

Output

```
IN:  I like apples more than oranges
OUT: I lk appls mr thn orngs
```

Comment: Hello, thank you. In this one, all vowels are deleted. I need one where in which vowels stay if they are the first letter in a word.

Comment: @Traveller You question somewhat obscure and you must correct it to reflect what you try to achieve. And for best result you must give a few examples of input and expected output.

Comment: I edited the code I first created. Sorry if my question is obscure, I edited it as well

Comment: @Traveler -- Do I understand you correctly: `$str = 'astringing';` will become `$str = 'astringing';` and `$str = 'stringing'` becomes `$str = 'strngng`? Add a few samples to your question for clarity.

Comment: It will become 'astrngng'. "a" will stay because it is at the beginning of the letter. "i" will be gone.

Comment: What about a criteria about first letter: if it is vowel then remove all vowels but very first, if it is not vowel then ....?

Comment: If it is not a vowel, then it will stay. This is my assignment and I need to use =~ tr/aeiouAEIOU//d, but not regex. We're also allowed to ask online if we cite it properly.

Comment: @Traveller -- if first letter isn't a vowel then all vowels stay in the string?

Comment: For example: "I like apples more than oranges" will become "I lk appls mr thn orngs"

Comment: What about: "This sentence is very short"?

Comment: Ths sntnc is vry shrt.

Comment: @Traveller -- please see addendum section of my answer